# aiogram 3.3.0: Чем мне заменить set в модуле FSMContext?

Tags: python, aiogram

Я делаю команду бана для бота, нашел статью, в которой команда бана реализована через `FSMContext`. Там сразу видно что `aiogram` старый.
Вот кусок кода который я переписал в свой:

```
@dp.message_handler(content_types=['text'], text='Добавить в ЧС')
async def hanadler(message: types.Message, state: FSMContext):
  if message.chat.id == ADMIN:
    keyboard = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True)
    keyboard.add(types.InlineKeyboardButton(text="Назад"))
    await message.answer('Введите id пользователя, которого нужно заблокировать.\nДля отмены нажмите кнопку ниже', reply_markup=keyboard)
    await dialog.blacklist.set() # Вот здесь подсвечивается жёлтым
```

При наведении на `set()` написано что такого атрибута в модуле `State` нет. Как его заменить?
Пользуюсь редактором `PyCharm`. На всякий случай ссылка на статью с туториалом - https://habr.com/ru/articles/599199/

Comment: `state.set_state(dialog.blacklist)` попробуйте так

Comment: @gord1402 а как со `state.finish()`?

Comment: @Nqweqweqwe `await state.clear()` теперь вместо `state.finish()`. [полезная ссылка 1](https://docs.aiogram.dev/en/latest/migration_2_to_3.html#finite-state-machine) [полезная ссылка 2](https://docs.aiogram.dev/en/latest/dispatcher/finite_state_machine/index.html#finite-state-machine)

Comment: @Be3y4uu_K0T Спасибо за ссылки =)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решить вопрос помогли два пользователя: @gord1402, @be3y4uu-k0t,
Ответ пользователя @gord1402:

> `state.set_state(dialog.blacklist)` попробуйте так

Ответ пользователя @be3y4uu-k0t:

> await state.clear() теперь вместо state.finish()

Спасибо им большое =)